# Map RAID device to OS level device

Tags: linux, raid

I have a two RAIDs, named 'raid1' and 'raid2', that show up on my linux machine as `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`.  How can I tell which RAID maps to which device?

I can do this with an Adaptec card by looking in `/sys/block/sd?/device/model`.  The contents of that file will be the name of the raid (i.e. 'raid1' or 'raid2').  However, there does not look to be a simple way to do this with an LSI RAID card.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't there an LSI linux tool that lets you do that ? It's been a while since i used one but i'm pretty sure there is.

Comment: There is a command line utility for LSI called megacli.  It will list information about RAIDs, but it doesn't list anything about what the RAID is referred to as on the OS.

Comment: really ? I could have sworn that it had the raid names down as the same as the OS refers to them as. May be a different tool I'm thinking of, or perhaps I'm mistaken. :(